# how do I scan and scroll with elasticsearch-js and elasticsearch 5.0

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch.js

I was using `elasticsearch-scrolltoend` as a plugin previously, after upgrading to 5.0 the plugin doesn't seem to work.  How can I scan and scroll a large dataset with elasticsearch 5.0?

I also received an error when attempting to use the implementation in the 
[elasticsearch-js docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-scroll):

`json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse request body"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse request body",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "json_parse_exception",
      "reason": "Unrecognized token 'DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBQAAAAAAAAHKFnV6a2NabEh4VDZLQmdzUzY0Y2tpd0EAAAAAAAAByxZ1emtjWmxIeFQ2S0Jnc1M2NGNraXdBAAAAAAAAAcwWdXprY1psSHhUNktCZ3NTNjRja2l3QQAAAAAAAAHOFnV6a2NabEh4VDZLQmdzUzY0Y2tpd0EAAAAAAAABzRZ1emtjWmxIeFQ2S0Jnc1M2NGNraXdB': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@67ba4d99; line: 1, column: 457]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}`

Answer (score 0):

The unrecognized token response error is a bug that was fixed in `13.0.0-rc1` -- see [this issue for reference](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/522)

As for the implementation, [heres how I did it without the elasticsearch-scrolltoend plugin](https://gist.github.com/ilovett/ded3b19af01f05f8022413067bd6275a)

```
  // methods in some ES6 class
  ...

  fetchStuff(min, max = min) {

    const body = new Bodybuilder();

    body.size(3);
    body.filter('range', 'timestamp', {
      gte: min,
      lte: max
    });

    return this.elasticsearch.search({
      index: 'my-alias',
      type: 'my-doc',
      body: body.build('v2'), // have not upgraded to newer bodybuilder package yet
      scroll: '15s'
    })
    .then((res) => this._scrollToEnd(res, []))
    .then((events) => {

      // sort by timestamp then _id
      events = _.sortBy(events, ['_.source.timestamp', '_id']);

      return events;

    });

  }

  _scrollToEnd(res, events) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {

      events = events.concat(_.get(res, 'hits.hits', []));

      if (res.hits.total > events.length) {
        return this.elasticsearch.scroll({
          scrollId: res._scroll_id,
          scroll: '15s'
        })
        .then((res) => this._scrollToEnd(res, events));
      }

      return events;

    });
  }
```